# Export Birt Report to Excel

Tags: java, report, birt

Am trying to export **Birt Report** to **Excel**.If the report is having less number of records like hundreds then am able to export as excel.But if the report is having thousands of records then it throwing the following error.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
```

Comment: You are not looking at the exact error cause. Try more. From what are you saying, your application server could have easily run out of memory...

Comment: In server log am not able to see any exception which can help in finding the solution to this issue.Am assuming that when the report is having more than 1,50,000 records then it's failing to export the report to excel.Quer1)  Is there a away to specify the limit of the records that report has to export in the source code of Export To Excel plugin in Birt.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is the limitation of excel.Birt can able to export the report to excel if the records are 65k max else it will fail.

FYI:

[developer.actuate.com](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34531-xls-export-failing-for-large-data-birt-262/)

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to upgrade to BIRT 4.2 which allows you to [export to XLSX](https://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.2.php#jump_3) where you should not run into the 65K lines issue that exists with xls

Answer (score 0):

Update your BIRT version. And use the XLSX format than XLS.

Comment: Do you mean "then XLS" or "instead of XLS"?